# Half Witt algebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra, affine-lie-algebra

> I have the following Lie algebra which is generated by $\{L_n|n\geq 0\}.$ It satisfies the following commutation rule
>   $$ \Big[ L_i ,L_j \Big]=\frac18 \frac{(2i+2j-1)(2j-2i)}{(2j+1)(2i+1)}L_{i+j-1}-\frac12 \frac{(2i+2j+1)(2j-2i)}{(2j+1)(2i+1)}L_{i+j}.$$
>   My question is that if the algebra algebra defined above is a half witt algebra?

I thought we can conclude by seeing the commutator relation of $L_n$ but it
can happen there 
 exists a change of basis say $\{V_n| n\geq 0\}$ such that where 
$$V_n=\sum_{\text{finite sum over some indedx}}L_k  $$ 
such that 
 $$\Big[ V_i ,V_j \Big]=[i-j]V_{i+j}~?$$
How can I conclude it is not a witt algebra etc?

Comment: What an unfortunate name for a subject. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start with the obvious rescaling
$$
\tilde{L}_i = (2i + 1)L_i\,,
$$
which turns the algebra to
$$
[\tilde{L}_i,\tilde{L}_j] = (i-j)\left(\tilde{L}_{i+j}-\frac{1}{4}\tilde{L}_{i+j-1}\right)\,.
$$
Then one can tentatively postulate a change of basis of the form
$$
V_i = \sum_{m=0}^i a_m\,\tilde{L}_m\,.
$$
Let's work out the algebra, let's just say without loss of generality that $i>j$.
$$
[V_i,V_j] = \sum_{m=0}^i\sum_{n=0}^j a_ma_n\,(m-n)\left(\tilde{L}_{m+n}-\frac{1}{4}\tilde{L}_{m+n-1}\right)\,,
$$
change summation variable to $(m,n) \to (M = m+n, N = m-n)$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\,[V_i,V_j] &= \sum_{M=0}^{i+j}\sum_{\substack{N=\max(-M,M-2j)\\N\equiv M \mod 2}}^{\min(M,2i-M)}a_{\frac{M+N}{2}}a_{\frac{M-N}{2}} N\left(\tilde{L}_{M}-\frac{1}{4}\tilde{L}_{M-1}\right)=\\&=
\sum_{M=1}^{i+j}\sum_{\substack{N=\max(-M,M-2j)\\N\equiv M \mod 2}}^{\min(M,2i-M)}a_{\frac{M+N}{2}}a_{\frac{M-N}{2}} N\,\tilde{L}_{M}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{\tilde{M}=0}^{i+j-1}\sum_{\substack{N=\max(-\tilde{M}-1,\tilde{M}+1-2j)\\N\equiv \tilde{M}+1 \mod 2}}^{\min(\tilde{M}+1,2i-\tilde{M}-1)}a_{\frac{\tilde{M}+N+1}{2}}a_{\frac{\tilde{M}-N+1}{2}} N\,\tilde{L}_{\tilde{M}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Where I replaced $\tilde{M} +1 = M$ in the second term. Now we can group everything by simply dropping the $\sim$ and obtain an equation of the form
$$
[V_i,V_j] = \sum_{M=0}^{i+j} b_M^{(i,j)}\,\tilde{L}_M\,,
$$
for some coefficients $b_M^{(i,j)}$ that are defined as the whole mess above. Finally the equation seeked it
$$
b_M^{(i,j)} = (i-j)\, a_M\,.
$$
I have no idea if this equation has solutions or not, but it's more concrete so perhaps one can try and see if there are solutions for the first two or three values of $i,j$. If you find it, there might be a way to prove that it exists always. If you find an obstruction it might be that the change of basis I chose was not general enough or that there are no solutions indeed. The inexistence of solutions implies that the algebras are not isomorphic.

This is not by any means a complete answer, but hopefully it goes in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will get to work on the equation for the existence of the solution.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how feasible it is, I didn't try it. So don't hold me responsible if it keeps you up at night ;)

Comment: Well, I will post problems to keep you up lol :)

Comment: $a_{\text{negative}}=0$ so that would change the lower limit in the sum of $N$.

Comment: It will be starting from zero and upper limit of N should be i?

Comment: I spent some time thinking about the right limits of summation, I think they are correct. If you define $a$ out of bounds to be zero yes, you can extend the sum.

Comment: With the change of basis, you suggest I use $V_i = \sum_{m=0}^{i}a_{im}$ (i add the $aim$ not just $a_m$) I get $V_2 =0$ by the condition $[V_2, V_0]=2V_2$. Hence can we say that this change of basis won't work?

Comment: I am unsure by your phrasing. I did not suggest to use that ansatz... indeed what I think would be likely to work, if anything works at all, is to sum the $a_m$ *up to* $i$ and not, as in your example, up to $i^2$, which obviously gives a completely wild change of basis,

Comment: I do sum upto $i$ So $V_1 = a_{10}L_0 +a_{11}L_1$ $V_2 = a_{20}L_0 + a_{21}L_1 + a_{22}L_2 $.  What you suggested is $a_{20}=a_{10}$ and $a_21 =a_11$ I just made this relation independent.

Comment: Even if you take the basis as you defined with the relation $[V_1 , V_0]=V_1 $ we get $a_0 =1$ and $a_1=4$ but using $[V_2 , V_0]=V_0$ we get $a_2 =0 , a_1 =0  hence there does not exsit a solution?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you meant $a_{i \times m}$. Now I see what you mean and I agree. Probably then you are right. I find it weird though because I imagine that even infinite Lie algebras are to some extent classified, so if you come up with some algebra, either it is a known one in a convoluted disguise or it has some sickness. I am not expert on this subject...

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help. If you know something please update.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\lambda$, consider the commutation relations
$$
[L_i,L_j] = (i-j)(L_{i+j} + \lambda L_{i+j-1})
$$
These relations obey antisymmetry and Jacobi identities so we have a Lie algebra. To make it look like the Witt algebra it is tempting to set $\tilde{L}_i = L_i -\lambda L_{i-1}$, which leads to 
$$
[\tilde{L}_i,\tilde{L}_j] = (i-j)\tilde{L}_{i+j} + O(\lambda^2)
$$
We then have to add terms of higher order in $\lambda$. We get an infinite series unless we can consistently truncate the algebra i.e. restrict to $i\geq 0$. I am not sure of that last point.

Comment: I will check what you said. For the algebra $i\geq 0$ that why I call it half witt.